# SmartGWT how to know if any Window is visible on the screen?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have an editor application with a main editor area in SmartGwt. I handle some native events - keypresses as keyboard shortcuts. I want to disable executing these when there's one or more Window shown on the screen. How to detect if there are any Window descendants shown? /I don't mean browser windows, but SmartGwt Window descendants/
It would be perfectly enough to detect modal windows.
Is there a SmartGwt API way of doing this, or I have to create my own system for registering my windows and query their visible state?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - there seems to be no other way of doing this than creating a common ancestor for my windows and keep track of the visibility changes.
Then call getVisibleCount() when needed.

```
public class WindowBase extends Window {
private static ArrayList<Window> visibleWindows = new ArrayList<Window>();
VisibilityChangedHandler handlervc = new VisibilityChangedHandler() {

public void onVisibilityChanged(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.VisibilityChangedEvent event) {
    if ( event.getIsVisible() ) {
        if ( !visibleWindows.contains( event.getSource() ) )
            visibleWindows.add( (Window)event.getSource() );
    }   else 
        visibleWindows.remove( event.getSource() );
}
};

@Override 
public void show() {
    if ( !visibleWindows.contains( this ) )
        visibleWindows.add( this );
    addVisibilityChangedHandler( handlervc );
    super.show();
}

public static int getVisibleCount() {
    return visibleWindows.size();
}
```

}